# Проблема с добавлением элементов в map

Tags: java

не могу понять почему при добавлении кириллицы((char) int) в ключ HashMap с определенной итерации элементы начинают добавляться в начало

```
Map<Character, Integer> alph = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 1072; i <= 1103; i++) {
    alph.put((char) i, 0);
}
```

хотя тот же цикл, только при добавлении латиницы (97-122) все нормально

Answer (score 1):

Порядок элементов при итерации по `HashMap` не гарантируется. То, что в каких-то случаях он может совпадать с порядком вставки - стечение обстоятельств, надеяться на это нельзя.

Пользуйтесь `LinkedHashMap`. В этой реализации `Map` итерация по элементам всегда производится в порядке вставки.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То есть в случае с латиницей просто повезло?

Answer (score 0):

Порядок элементов в `HashMap` произвольный - не зря же она так называется.

Если нужна отсортированная, то используй `SortedMap`.

А если в порядке добавления, то мне неизвестно, есть ли подходящая коллекция в джаве.

Comment: Но с латиницей все нормально заносит в map и выводит

Comment: @Mrian_, ну и что? Там числа мелкие - скорее всего поэтому.

Comment: LinkedHashMap сохраняет порядок вставки

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, думаю, это стоит ответом запостить.